# Merging multiple HTML files into one and return output

Tags: php, templates

I am trying to find the cleanest way to merge multiple html files into one html file. This way I can easily change parts of the html or show them only on certain pages. The file list is as followed:

1. page.tpl (header, footer, head info)
2. sidebar.tpl (contains sidebar and sidebar blocks)
3. nav.tpl(contains navigation links in nested UL)

The page.tpl file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="author" content="Brandon" />
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <?php print $stylesheets; ?>
    <?php print $scripts; ?>
</head>
<body>
<section id="wrapper">
<header>Header Title</header>
<nav><?print $nav; ?></nav>
<section><?php print $content; ?></section>
<aside> <?php print $sidebar; ?><aside>
<footer>&copy; 2011 Brandon License: GPLv2</footer>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

The main function I have to include everything is:

```
function theme($tpl, $vars = array()) {
    extract($vars);
    ob_start();

    require($tpl);
    $template = ob_get_contents();

    ob_end_clean();

    return $template;
}
```

$tpl is set to the page.tpl file.

I tried `$vars['nav'] = file_get_contents('nav.tpl');` above the theme function just to give it some data to work with. If I remove the $tpl variable and the `require()` function, I see the UL nav list but when I add back the page.tpl file back in I get this error:

```
Warning: extract() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
```

This works(shows UL nav list):

```
$vars['nav'] = file_get_contents('nav.tpl');
function theme($vars = array()) {
    extract($vars);
    ob_start();

    $template = ob_get_contents();

    ob_end_clean();

    return $template;
}
```

This doesn't:

```
$vars['nav'] = file_get_contents('nav.html');
theme('page.html', $vars) //page.html is set to correct directory.
function theme($tpl, $vars = array()) {
    extract($vars);
    ob_start();

    require($tpl);
    $template = ob_get_contents();

    ob_end_clean();

    return $template;
}
```

Any help on getting this to work correctly would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**: This is my current index.php file:

```
    <?php

    define('ROOT_DIR', getcwd());

    require_once(ROOT_DIR . '/core/includes/boot.inc');

    boot_start(BOOT_FULL); 

// Based off of Drupal's drupal_bootstrap(). Set's ini_set's, database 
//and starts sessions. This works just fine and I haven't coded any 
//theme/template code into it. The only thing boot_start() does for theme is 
//load the .inc file that has the theme() function. The .inc gets included
// otherwise I would have gotten a "call to unknown function" error.

    $vars['nav'] = file_get_contents(ROOT_DIR . '/core/templates/nav.tpl');
    theme('./core/templates/page.tpl', $vars);
```

I don't quite understand why I am getting the error from `extract()`. When I add `$vars['nav']` without including 'include($tpl)', extract works just fine. It isn't until I try to include the page.tpl file.

The page.tpl file should be loaded on every page request that outputs anything. So I think I only need theme($vars) instead of theme($tpl, $vars = array())

Is there a way I can include page.tpl without passing it to theme(), while passing $vars so that $vars['nav'] overrides the `<?php print $nav; ?>` tag in page.tpl? Thanks.

**SOLVED**: Man, I can't believe it took me this long to fix this. Since theme() returned and not echo'ed the data, I had to assign `$theme = theme('page.tpl', $vars);` then `echo $theme;` Besides a few PHP notices, it works.

Comment: Brandon can you please accept some of your previous answered questions?

Comment: Mob, thanks. I accepted a few of my questions that had multiple answers.

Answer (score 0):

I personally just like to make a file for the individual parts. and then include them.

```
<?php include('relative/link.php'); ?>
```

if you want to edit the content in a section I would use variables.
header.php

```
echo $foo;
```

index.php

```
$foo='bar';
include('header.php');
```

when we include a file it grabs the contents and injects it in the current file and then will process it.

Comment: yamiko, I am building a script that relies on a front controller. So far the script goes through a bootstrap process, then routes to the correct page via a GET variable (q='page/edit'). I am basing a lot of my code on how Drupal works. I also like how Drupal handles theming, so I want to emulate that.

Comment: unfortunately I cant help you there. hopefully someone else comes by to help.